# Error: 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.document.getElementsByTagName')' when trying to initialize smartlook-client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to integrate smartlook to a react-native project. When I try to initialize smartlook, it returns TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.document.getElementsByTagName') in the first time rendered but when I press save the code again, it works. Anyone knows why? Pleas. Thank you

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import RootNavigation from './src/routes';
import {useFonts} from 'expo-font';
import fonts from './src/theme/fonts';
import {LogBox} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {
  requestTrackingPermissionsAsync,
  getTrackingPermissionsAsync,
} from 'expo-tracking-transparency';
import smartlookClient from 'smartlook-client';

const App = () => {
  smartlookClient.init('xxx');
  const [loaded] = useFonts(fonts);
  LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: ...']);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const {status} = await requestTrackingPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        console.log('Yay! I have user permission to track data');
      }
    })();
  }, []);
  Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
  Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
  TextInput.defaultProps = {
    ...(TextInput.defaultProps || {}),
    allowFontScaling: false,
  };
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
        translucent
        barStyle="dark-content"
        backgroundColor={'transparent'}
      />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RootNavigation />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
export default App;
```

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#fff',
},
});

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the smartlook example code [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smartlook-client) you will see that they wait for `componentDidMount` to initialize the client. You are using a function component as opposed to a class component. Therefore, you don't have `componentDidMount`. So the way to do the equivalent of `componentDidMount` in a function component would be:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // inside here is the same as componentDidMount
    smartlookClient.init('xxx')
}, [])
```

Comment: @Neil_Girardi I've tried it also and it still returns the same error..

Comment: @nmnhon Hmmm... you're sure that you included the empty dependency array in the useEffect call? If so, I'm out of ideas. I haven't worked with smartlook or react native. Is there an y sort of community around smartlook? If so, you might want to try surfacing the issue there. Good luck!

Comment: @nmnhon One more thing you can try is to comment out the call to `.init()` and any other references to that package except for the import. Do you still get the error? If so, then the error is happening on import. In that case, you can try lazy loading the library inside the useEffect hook and the run .init() as a callback.